# Ajax - How to use a returned array in a success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Hi I have a php code that returns an array. I want to be able to use this array in my ajax success function but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I have tried the following, but no luck.

php code:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "Mark Reed"
$arr[1] = "34";
$arr[2] = "Australia";

exit($arr);
```

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/returndetails.php",
    data: 'id=' + userid,
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
        document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = data[1];
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = data[2];
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `<?php exit(array());` and see what you get... you can NOT exit with an array like that...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should return the data as JSON from the server.

**PHP**

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "Mark Reed";
$arr[1] = "34";
$arr[2] = "Australia";

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/returndetails.php",
    data: 'id=' + userid,
    dataType: "json", // Set the data type so jQuery can parse it for you
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
        document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = data[1];
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = data[2];
    }
});
```

Comment: I did the same thing in your way but it turns out my data[x] is actually undefined. I can echo it in PHP with no problems...

Comment: Is there a way to parse an array within an array?

Answer (score 9):

A small mistake:

Not: `exit($arr);`

replace with: `echo json_encode($arr);`

Answer (score 5):

There a Problem , when you want display for example `data[0]` and `data[1]`, it seems like a character from string. It Solves adding  `header("Content-Type: application/json");` before apply `echo json_encode($arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "Mark Reed"
$arr[1] = "34";
$arr[2] = "Australia";

header("Content-Type: application/json");

echo json_encode($arr);

exit();
```

instead of

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "Mark Reed"
$arr[1] = "34";
$arr[2] = "Australia";

exit($arr);
```